# Mail function php changes format

Tags: php, html, email, layout

In my database I have the following text:

```
yyyy,

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx.

yyyy.
yyyyy.

xxxxx,

yyy
yyy
yyy
```

With php I tried to mail this message to someone, the text in the database is obtained by an HTML form, this is the php code:

```
$recipient = $emailadres;
    $subject = 'Bevestiging Inschrijving';
    $header = 'From: aaaaaa <aaa@aaaaaa.nl>';
    if ($aanhef == 'Dhr.') {
        $geslacht = 'heer';
    }
    elseif ($aanhef == 'Mevr.') {
        $geslacht = 'mevrouw';
    }
    else {
        $geslacht = 'heer/mevrouw';
    }
    $mail_body = $bevestiging;
    $mail_body = str_replace('#geslacht#', $geslacht, $mail_body);
    $mail_body = str_replace('#achternaam#', $achternaam, $mail_body);
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```

The mail arived in my mailbox looks like this:

```
yyyy,


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxx.


yyyy.

yyyyy.


xxxxx,


yyy

yyy

yyy
```

It adds an enter everywhere in the mail, how can i change that? I don't want to use format=text/html in $header because the mail will be caught by the spam filter then.

Comment: Hé Amsterdammer, Hm, why not trying to set your text into divs and give inline style with it?

Comment: Because the text is obtained by a HTML form, and i don't want to put it into divs everytime (amsterdam indeed!)

Comment: If you do it right, you only have to do it once ;) Just put it in a function and add divs around the vars. (I work near Amsterdam ;) )

Comment: I don't understand what variables you mean

Comment: Could it be that the text contains CRLFs and that the receiving mail client interprets both the CRs and the LFs as newlines? If so, the solution is to replace all `\r\n` by `\n` before sending.